# Trying to write a simple Blackjack, but there are errors I don't understand

Tags: c++

I have a problem with a code of mine. It gives random errors and I don't know why.. I'm a newbie to C++ so please bear with me >.>

Here is the code that's problematic:

```
while (!IsGameOver) {
    struct decktype deck = DeckInit();
    struct card card = PickACard(deck);
    PrintHand(TextCard(card));
}
```

The parameter for 'PrintHand' causes compilation errors no matter what I do. Here are both the functions.

```
char *TextCard(struct card &card) {
    char str[22];
    sprintf(str,"%s of %s (%d)",card_num[card.number],card_type[card.color],card.value);
    return str;
}


struct card PrintHand(char &cardtext) {
    struct card card;
    return card;
}
```

PrintHand isn't done yet, but I don't know how to make it work.. Basically what I want to do is feed a string from TextCard to be used in PrintHand. Could you please help? Much appreciated.

EDIT:

The structure 'card' at the moment looks like this.

```
struct card {
    int color;
    int number;
    int value;
    char *hand;
    int totalvalue;
};
```

And the errors are along the lines of "can't convert something to something". Sorry I couldn't be more specific :/

Comment: When asking a question about errors you receive, it's usually helpful to include the exact errors you get.

Comment: Show us structure _card_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a local variable and return it from function. Use *malloc* or *new* instead.

```
char str[22];

char * str = (char *) malloc(22* sizeof(char)); OR
String str = "sometext" + "othertext";
```

I don't know, what you are trying to do here:

```
struct card PrintHand(char &cardtext) {
    struct card card;
    return card;
}
```

If you want just print text, do this:

```
void PrintHand(char * cardtext) { // * instead of &
   printf("%s", cardtext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PrintHand` expect a reference to `char`, but you (i.e., `TextCard`) provide a pointer to `char`.

Comment: E.g., declare PrintHand as `struct card PrintHand(char *cardtext)`. However, it depends want you want, if you need a pointer or reference. I can not see that from code of `PrintHand`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors.

```
struct card PrintHand(char &cardtext) {
    struct card card;
    return card;
}
```

Doesn't use the cardtext, but the real error is the value passed to it from TextCard is char*, so this should be `struct card PrintHand(char *cardtext)`

Then:

```
char *TextCard(struct card &card) {
    char str[22];
    sprintf(str,"%s of %s (%d)",card_num[card.number],card_type[card.color],card.value);
    return str;
}
```

This returns, str, i.e. the address of str[0] which is on the stack, and disappers after TextCard returns, so **nothing** shoud use that return value. Either `new` some storage for the char array in the function return it, and have the caller cleanup, or pass in a char array from the caller.